# it is possible to "group by" without losing the original rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a query like this:

```
ID    |    name                     |    commentsCount
1     |    mysql for dummies        |    33
2     |    mysql beginners guide    |    22

SELECT
    ...,
    commentsCount    // will return 33 for first row, 22 for second one
FROM
    mycontents
WHERE
    name LIKE "%mysql%"
```

also i want to know the total of comments, of all rows:

```
SELECT
    ...,
    SUM(commentsCount) AS commentsCountAggregate    // should return 55
FROM
    mycontents
WHERE
    name LIKE "%mysql%"
```

but this one obviously returns a single row with the total.

now i want to merge these two queries in one single only,

because my actual query is very heavy to execute (it uses boolean full text search, substring offset search, and sadly lot more), then i don't want to execute it twice

is there a way to get the total of comments without making the SELECT twice?

**!! custom functions are welcome !!**

**also variable usage is welcome, i never used them...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious solution is storing intermediate results withing another 'temporary' table, and than perform aggregation in the second step.

Another solution is preparing a lookup table containing sums you need (but there obviously needs to be some grouping ID, I call it `MASTER_ID`), like that:

```
CREATE TABLE comm_lkp AS
SELECT MASTER_ID, SUM(commentsCount) as cnt
FROM mycontents
GROUP BY MASTER_ID
```

Also create an index on that table on column `MASTER_ID`. Later, you can modify your query like that:

```
SELECT
    ...,
    commentsCount,
    cnt as commentsSum
FROM
    mycontents as a
        JOIN comm_lkp as b ON (a.MASTER_ID=b.MASTER_ID)
WHERE
    name LIKE "%mysql%"
```

It also shouldn't touch your performance as long as lookup table will be relatively small.

Answer (score 2):

You can cache the intermediate result to a temporary table, and then do the sum over this table

Comment: yes, but i want to consider other solutions, because with my tests temporary tables are slow... +1s on a resultset of 100 rows :(

Comment: @toPeerOrNotToPeer - Why not tune your temporary tables like any other table - i.e. create an appropriate index on it.

Comment: you mean in-memory tables or normal tables?

Comment: Either way. It just adds more structure to how they are organized and hence accessed.

Answer (score 0):

A GROUP BY on one of the ID fields might do the trick. This will then give you the SUM(commentsCount) for each ID.

The query in your question is not detailed enough to know which of your fields/tables the ID field should come form.